# Identify important interactions terms in SVM with polynomial kernel

Tags: svm, interaction, polynomial, importance

I have an SVM model with polynomial kernel.  I have output of feature weights, but they are all the individual features. Is there a way to know which interactions between individual features are most important in the separation of data points for the SVM model?

Comment: Have a look at the work by Brown et al. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ioannis_Tsamardinos/publication/287330058_IDA_post_print/links/56756cac08aebcdda0e4629d/IDA-post-print.pdf

Comment: Thanks @George!  This is awesome.  Do you know if one of their heuristic approaches has been  implemented in R?

Comment: In the paper the authors state they have implemented it in Matlab. You should probably contact the authors to ask if there is an R implementation or to at least give you the Matlab code so you have a good starting point.